# Convert a row and column sorted 2-D array to a sorted 1-D array

Tags: algorithm, matrix, array-algorithms

Given an 2-D Array of n*n elements:

- all rows are sorted
- all columns are sorted

For example:

```
1 5 7
2 6 8
3 9 10
```

convert it to a 1-D sorted array. Is there a solution better than `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: This isn't really the place to post HW

Comment: @Noam : This is not a homework question . This is an interview question . I have been thinking about it for a while but not able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well it can't be less than `n^2` complexity, because you have `n^2` elements that you'll have to examine at least once each.

The algorithm to do this is a standard k-way merge, which has a complexity of `N log k`, where `N` is the total number of items to be merged, and `k` is the number of sequences.

In your `n*n` array, you have `n*n` items to be merged and `n` sequences (i.e. rows). So, substituting in the equation above:

```
N log k
N = (n*n)
k = n
(n*n) log n
```

Turning your 2D array into a sorted 1D array is `n^2 log n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function f(x,y) = (f(x),f(y)) to reduce the complexity and flatten the 2d array. It's also reorder the 1d array. Since it's a function it's more like a hashing algorithm and maybe not what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you explain what f(x,y) = (f(x),f(y)) means ?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your `O(n log n)` solution: The truth is, no such solution is really possible. Here is why. You have `n*n` elements. So the best you can do is `n^2` since you must visit each element at least once. Just think about it. You have to fill a 1-D array of length `n*n` (i.e. every element of the 2-D array must exist in the new 1-D array). Therefore there is no way you can solve this problem in `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

i have a time: O(n*n log(2n)) space O(2n) algorithm.

basic idea would be as follows

a[0][0] would be the smallest element for sure.     Because elements     are row wise and column wise sorted, the next smallest element will      be min( a[0][1], a[1][0] ).  say, a[0][1] is smallest of the two,    next candidate will be min(a[0][2],a[1][1],a[1][0])

And so on,

**Algo:**

pick the smallest of the candidate elements, print it. push the element to right and bottom of the smallest element as potential candidates. (check for out or bound.)
  Do this till no more candidate element exist.

**DS required:**

The candidate elements can be maintained using heap (top is min element) But u need to make sure u dont push the same element twice. (y could be right of x and bottom of z). 
  Before u push to heap u need to know if the element is already pushed.

Both these requirements are gracefully handled by set (which is ordered) (i code in c++)

Storing index in the set will allow me to push the next candidate elements to candidate Ds easily.
  in my candidate ds, i maintain no more than n+n elements at any point of time
  the following is the compare function i use.

```
bool operator()(const int& a,const int& b) const{
        int ai=a/m,aj=a%m;
        int bi=b/m,bj=b%m;
        if(input[ai][aj]!=input[bi][bj])
        return input[ai][aj]<input[bi][bj];
        else
        return a<b;
    }
```

a sample implementation is here: http://ideone.com/w208Af

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in O(n). I disagree that this is impossible to do faster then n^2 because in this case n*n=n because when you are talking time complexity you are referring to the number of elements in the list. Here is O(n) solution where n = min-max. For this to work you need to know the lowest number and highest number that could be in the list. You don't need to know what they are just the lowest and highest possible.

```
    int[] Sorted1dArray(int[][] arr, int min, int max)//basically counting sort
    {
       int index = 0;
       int rowColSize = arr[0].Length;
       int[] newArr = new int[max-min];
       int[] ret = new int[rowColSize *rowColSize ];
       for(int i=0;i<rowColSize ;i++)//
       {
          for(int j=0;j<rowColSize ;j++)
             newArr[arr[i][j]]++;
       }
       for(int i=0;i<newArr.Length;i++)
       {
          for(int j=0;j<newArr[i];j++)
          {
             ret[index++]=newArr[j];
          }
       }
       return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Saying that `n*n=n` is confusing the issue. Regardless, if you have k sorted lists containing a total of n items, merging them into a single sorted list requires O(n log k) time. You can't in the general case do it any faster than that.

Comment: The code above is in linear time where n=min-max. It goes through the lists one time then populates newArr in one iteration then goes through newArr one more time to create ret. Are you suggesting that this is false?

Comment: Your code has several bugs. First, it throws `IndexOutOfRangeException` when run against the OP's data it tries to index `newArr[10]`. And all that first set of loops does (if the items in question were 0 through 8, it would work) is initialize every item in `newArr` to 1. That said, your counting sort idea can work in O(n) if there are n numbers in sequence such that `max-min+1 == n`, and there are no duplicates. But those conditions do not hold for the OP's example.

Comment: You are correct I made a small mistake. However duplicates don't matter. That is why the you increment the index everytime there is a duplicate. So for example if all the numbers were 1 you would have an array where the first index would have a value of 9. To correct my mistake you would have to set the array to have the size of the max which in this case would be 10. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the approach I would take:

1) start with the first row - "1 5 7". We know that at the start, the rows are sorted, so we are guaranteed that the left-most element is the least, with no comparisons needed. Output the 1, and shift the first column up, giving us "2 5 7".

2) Now compare the first two elements. As long as the first element is less than the second, keep outputting the first element and shifting its respective column up. That gives us output
of 2 and 3 with the resulting array being "5 7" (since the first column is now empty).

3) Continue doing the same thing with the remaining two colums. This will give us output of 5 and 6 before we run into the first case where something's different - our array will contain "9 7" at this point.

4) In this case, we'll output the value from the last column and shift that one up, giving us "9 8" after outputting 7. We again have the case where the first element is greater, so we'll output the second and shift that column up, leaving us with "9 10".

Haven't analyzed it thoroughly, but I think that's O(N), as there's a maximum of N comparisons due to the assumptions you can make about the relations between the individual columns.